# Implement script in dynamically created textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

Problem - On my html page there's one textarea. Code is -

```
<div id ="textFields" class="form-group">
        <p align="center">
        <br>
        <textarea placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5" id="note" style="width: 80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea>
            <script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'note' );</script>
         </p>
</div>
```

Now I want to create multiple textareas, for which I'm using an Add button and the jQuery code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addNew").click(function () {
    var inputField = jQuery('<p align="center"><br><textarea placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5" id="note" style="width: 80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea><script>CKEDITOR.replace( 'note' );</script></p>');
    jQuery('#textFields').append(inputField);
}); });
```

When I click the `#addNew` button, the textarea is created but the CKEditor script is not loaded. This results in a plain textarea without CKEditor's functionalities.

How do I create a new textarea with CKEditor functionalities? Is there another way? Is my approach wrong?

Comment: Your textarea's ID has to be unique. You can append an incremented counter to it. Make sure you use the same in the `<textarea>` tag and the call to `CKEDITOR.replace`.

Also don't add the `<script>` tag when creating the jQuery object, just call the function after appending the textarea element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an id is an unique identifier in html and you shouldn't use it more than once.

Second, you can't add script tags, which get executed, that way. I would suggest to restructure your code like this

```
<div id ="textFields" class="form-group">
    <p align="center">
        <br>
        <textarea id="note0" placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width: 80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea>
    </p>
</div>
```

with the following javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var note_id = 0;
    CKEDITOR.replace('note0');
    $("#addNew").click(function () {
        note_id++;
        var inputField = $('<p align="center"><br><textarea id="note' + note_id + '" placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width: 80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea></p>');
        $('#textFields').append(inputField);
        CKEDITOR.replace('note' + note_id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man.
I forgot about the unique textarea id.
The CKEditor method you showed helped a lot. Guess I have to learn javascript properly.
Many thanks.